# html5, nav and sections, how to load a page in a section from a nav element click

Tags: html, css, layout

I am new to html5.  I have a nav tag.  I would like to create a vertical split with the nav on the left hand side.

If a user clicks a link in the nav, page will show up on the right hand side in a  tag.

How do I do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with html5 besides the tag names. It would also be helpful to know your markup and whether you are using any Javascript libraries like jQuery.

Comment: Please show us with a picture or jsFiddle what your desired outcome is.

Comment: I am not using jquery but now I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you would do something like this:

```
$("nav > a").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $("section#content").load(url);
    return false;
});
```